# Looking for computationally intensive GIS operation for parallelization in which Arc GIS takes long time to execute

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, gis

I want to develop parallel algorithms for compute-intensive and time taking vector GIS operations. I have tried doing polygon overlay earlier. Looking for other operations as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised how long "Merge" took even with relatively small shapefiles but large numbers of variables. When one has to merge multiple shapefiles together it can be prohibitive. Seems like it might be a good choice for parallelization.